# how to create access point on android

Tags: android

I want to programmatically create access point (or hot spot sharing) on `android` phones and get all passes that users entered to connect the access point. for example make a service that count the users  that want to connect my access point and their pass were "pass1" or "pass2" or "pass3". can any one  help me to do this android project?

i want to make an app that :

1. create an protected access point on phone(like "hot spot" sharing)
2. i want to save all entered passwords (correct or not correct pass) to connect my access point (save the passes that are correct or not correct)

Answer (score 0):

Android has a linux kernel. There are many projects for Raspberry Pi with "hostapd" for create a access point. This also should work on Andorid. But i think u have to use the 3G or LTE connection for the internet, cause when your mobile wifi-adapter send as a access point or hot spot it cant also have a connection to your router. May a Raspberry with LAN and WIFI-Adapter is a better solution for the project. 
Then you could host with a websever like lighttpd a website, the users must logon and grab with a php script or sth. else the passwords.

Comment: is there any way to do this only  with android (using eclipse and java)?

Comment: The hostapd part and the little webserver you should be able to install and configure . Do you want to use the 3G/LTE connection for the connected users to your hot spot or do you want to use another wifi connection. If i can help u a bit , iam happy when you vote up my answer :p

Comment: i think i should use wifi connection .(sorry i am new member of stackoverflow and can not vote yet ):

Comment: then i dont see an answer for using a android phone cause the reason i telled you in the answer. A Raspberry Pi is no alternative ?

Comment: but when a devise want to connect to my devise send an information packet that have pass and any other information . is there any way to read that packet ?

Comment: for example the  shareit app create an hotspot and other devices can connect to it .

Comment: e.g. you can sniff any connection with wireshark. but you also can write a php code which save all log in data u give into your own website . there are many solutions . it would help if you say what specific you want to do with these passwords etc

Comment: how can i sniff the information ? wireshark is android app ?  - i want to create an access point and see witch passwords peoples or hackers use to connect to my access point .

Comment: Wireshark is a desktop application and you can see all trafic which happens with the connected devices, which are in the same network. If you have more questions to wireshark please open a new question!